# How to blink a label in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to blink a label in asp.net page but when i put the  then its blink the whole page, not that label.

Comment: Blink tag is non-standard, and it's generally not recommended: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element

Comment: what is the reason that you did not upvote any of these answers?

Comment: I recommend revising your question body. The sentence is confusing and there is no code given.

Answer (score 3):

## Blink Text With Random Color in Java Script

### In Script Tag

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var hexvalues
= Array( "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" );

        function flashtext() {
               
           var colour = '#';
           for( var counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter ++ ) {
            var hexvalue = hexvalues[ Math.floor( hexvalues.length * Math.random() ) ];

                colour = colour + hexvalue;

            }
           document.getElementById( "flashingtext" ).style.color = colour;
             } 

       setInterval("flashtext()", 500 );

    

</script>
```

### and Write it in Body section

```
<div id="flashingtext" style="font-size:25px;">    
    JavaScript Flashing Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use Jquery blink plugin..

[Jquery Blink](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blink)

```
$('.blink').blink(); // default is 500ms blink interval.
//$('.blink').blink(100); // causes a 100ms blink interval
```

.

Comment: That must have been crafted by the "league of evil, evil jQuery plugin writers".

Comment: @Jamiec im new to web development, and would like to know what you mean by it being evil? i thought it was cool and useful

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов = Very early on in the web, browsers understood a `<blink>` html tag and blinked whatever text was inside. It was deemed to be awful for usability, awful for accessibility, and just awful to look at - in other words evil. As browsers moved on, this tag was consigned to the history books.And from wiki: "The blink element has been consistently criticised by usability and accessibility experts. In 1996 Jakob Nielsen described the element as "simply evil" in his Alertbox column Top Ten Mistakes in Web Design"

Comment: @Jamiec sorry i meant why are you saying jquery is evil?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов - I didnt! Where did I say that? I think you've missed something in the subtlety of the english language :)

Comment: this one i thin kleague of evil, evil jQuery plugin writers

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Startblink()
{
    var lbl = document.getElementById('Label1');
    lbl.style.textDecoration = 'blink';
}
</script>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="Blink" onclick="Startblink();" />
```

On Button click

```
Label1.Attributes.Add("style", "text-decoration:blink");
```

Comment: If not use the below link 

http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/227/make-a-label-control-blink

Answer (score 0):

I Tried this

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Add blinking effect to text in jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
blinkeffect('#txtblnk');
})
function blinkeffect(selector) {
$(selector).fadeOut('slow', function() {
$(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
blinkeffect(this);
});
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="txtblnk"> <p><strong><font color="red">Blinking Effect Using Jquery</font></strong></p> </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is 100% working. refer from [here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/02/add-blinking-text-using-jquery-blinking.html)